# Putting android:largeHeap="true" cause different behavior in different devices

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am developing an app which has so many icons in it.Each icons are of 512x512px and size 29kb.It's working in emulator properly. But when I run it in a real device, it causes out of memory error. So I searched in google and found a solution as put android:largeHeap="true" in manifest. It's working to somewhat extend but it creates an odd behavior in less memory devices. That is fragments are messing up and data is not loading from web service to RecyclerView. But When I removed it's working in that devices. I don't know what is the issue in it.
the error I'm getting is:

> Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828-byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have to create icons for every screen density bucket and place them in appropriate drawable folder. Or place your existing icons in drawable-xhdpi folder

Comment: Try with resize those images 512x512 to 300x300. Hope this will work.

Comment: thanks i will try and tell the result

Comment: i am sorry for the late reply.yes @FaysalAhmed its solved.Thank you FaysalAhmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image size is too large for showing. Try to resize the image size

```
512x512
```

to

```
300x300
```

Hope your problem will be fixed.